# How to use \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff inside tikzset?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, expl3, latex3

If you place `ExplSyntax` on/off inside `tikzset`, code (that is expected to work) within `ExplSyntax` would generate errors. But if you bring `ExplSyntax` outside of `tikzset` (enclosing the `tikzset`), it makes `tikzset` behave unexpectedly. How can I use `ExplSyntax` inside `tikzset`? Or do I need to (disappointingly, yet again) search for work arounds?

### Block within `ExplSyntax` generates an error inside `tikzset`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \int_new:N\myCounter
  \int_set:Nn\myCounter{0}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset
  { every node/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \ExplSyntaxOn
            % following line generates an error
            % \int_incr:N\myCounter
            \ExplSyntaxOff
          }
      }
  }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node{some text};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### Although block within ExplSyntax does not generate an error, it does not increment `\myCounter`, causes labels and positioning commands (who knows what else) within `tikzset` to generate errors, and prevents a standard counter (`myStandardCounter`) from being incremented:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{myStandardCounter}

% let's bring ExplSyntax outside of tikzset and try again
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \int_new:N\myCounter
  \int_set:Nn\myCounter{0}
  \tikzset
    { every node/.style=
        { /utils/exec=
            { % neither of the counters below are incremented
              \int_incr:N\myCounter
              \stepcounter{myStandardCounter}
            }
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node{some text};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % both counters are at their initial values (zero)

  \ExplSyntaxOn
    expl3~counter:~\int_use:N\myCounter
  \ExplSyntaxOff

  standard counter: \the\value{myStandardCounter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It won't work inside. You have to set the catcodes (i.e., `\ExplSyntaxOn`) before the command (`\tikzset`) reads its argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, catcode changes (`\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\makeatletter`, `\ExplSyntaxOff`/`\makeatother`, and the like) will not work inside macro arguments. TeX turns a input character into a so-called *token* when it first sees that character. When you do:

```latex
\tikzset
  {
    /utils/exec=
      {
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \int_incr:N \myCounter
        \ExplSyntaxOff
      }
  }
```

The `\tikzset` macro grabs everything between `{` and `}` as argument and, at this point, TeX “sees” those characters, which are turned into tokens using the current catcode regime (with `\ExplSyntaxOff`), so `\int_incr:N \myCounter` is tokenized as `\int` `_` `i` `n` `c` `r` `:` `N`  `\myCounter`, and this tokenization is “frozen”, which means you can't change it.

After that the `/utils/exec` key does its thing and `\ExplSyntaxOn` is executed, but at this point it's too late, so it won't work.

---

Second, using your last code with `\ExplSyntaxOn` outside. Remember that in the `expl3` syntax spaces are ignored, so the `every node/.style` key is actually `everynode/.style`. And in Ti*k*Z spaces *do* matter. You need `every~node/.style`.

And last, you execute the node code inside a `tikzpicture` environment, and this creates a bunch of grouping levels, so any local assignment is lost when the `\end{tikzpicture}` is reached. You need to use `\int_gincr:N` to make it work (LaTeX's `\stepcounter` uses global assignments).

Output:

> [image]

Working code:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{myStandardCounter}

% let's bring ExplSyntax outside of tikzset and try again
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \int_new:N \myCounter
  \int_gset:Nn \myCounter {0}
  \tikzset
    { every~node/.style=
        { /utils/exec=
            { % neither of the counters below are incremented
              \int_gincr:N \myCounter
              \stepcounter{myStandardCounter}
            }
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node{some text};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % both counters are at their initial values (zero)

  \ExplSyntaxOn
    expl3~counter:~\int_use:N\myCounter
  \ExplSyntaxOff

  standard counter: \the\value{myStandardCounter}

\end{document}
```