# Using custom units with siunitx v3 in captions - is \protect insufficient?

Tags: captions, siunitx, protected-macro, fragile

I am using my [previously discussed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621035/134641) custom commands (also provided below), in [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). Since version 3, I am no longer able to use them in captions, whereas previously, adding `\protect` before them always worked.

Definition (in a loaded `sty` file):

```
% Define "quantity-product", as an alias in versions prior to 3.0; allows its unconditional use
% From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621037/134641
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}  % main release of 3.0.0
    { } {
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
            { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
        \ExplSyntaxOFf
    }
%--------------------------------------------

\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = \;]\basepair{bp}
```

Usage example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Pertains to $\SI{500}{\protect\basepair}$ regions and uncalibrated data.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`siunitx` makes unit macros `\protected`, so they don't explode when used in expansion-only contexts, like in captions, so you can simply use `\SI{500}{\basepair}` without having to worry about protection (otherwise you'd have to `\protect\SI` too).  Here's the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}  % main release of 3.0.0
  { }
  {
    \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
      { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = \;]\basepair{bp}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Pertains to $\SI{500}{\noexpand\basepair}$ regions and uncalibrated data.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When you added `\protect` you made it break because inside a `\caption`, `\protect` is `\@unexpandable@protect`, so it prevents the expansion of the following token with `\noexpand`, so you essentially have `\SI{500}{\noexpand\basepair}` (if you try this, you'll get the same error).  Then, when `siunitx` goes parsing the unit (at which point every unit macro is defined to have their correct meaning), it doesn't expand `\basepair`, and then later when typesetting, `\basepair` is expanded, but then it is back to being `\ERROR`.

As a rule of thumb, adding `\protect` is the exception rather than the norm, so only add it if you know that the macro will explode (but then consider making it robust with `\MakeRobust`).

---

Note that, in the code:

```
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}  % main release of 3.0.0
    { } {
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
            { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    }
```

the `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are doing nothing (and I'm surprised you didn't get an "Undefined control sequence \keys" error when running that). There's an explanation at the beginning of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491235/134574), but that code should be:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}  % main release of 3.0.0
  { }
  {
    \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
      { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In your case `\makeatletter` is not necessary because it's in a `.sty` file (`\makeatletter` is on by default in packages and classes), but note that in the example above I also added it outside the braces: inside it would have done nothing useful.